# How to Inherit nested class from Base class in Derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, nested

base.h

```
#ifndef BASE_H
#define BASE_H

class Base {
public:
    // Forward declaration
    class Nested;
};

class Derived : public Base {

};

#endif
```

nested.h:

```
#ifndef NESTED_H
#define NESTED_H

class Derived::Nested {

};

#endif
```

main.cc:

```
#include "base.h"
#include "nested.h"

int main() {
    Derived derived = Derived();
}
```

But the compiler errors:

```
./nested.h:4:16: error: no class named 'Nested' in 'Derived'
class Derived::Nested {
      ~~~~~~~~~^
1 error generated.
```

I'm dealing with legacy code, and trying to extract the Base class.
I think nested class Nested in Base is a type, and I've declared it as public, shouldn't Derived inherit it? Or, is any way to do so?

Comment: I can't reproduce it: https://godbolt.org/z/KGn6dv But I got error C2427 from msvc compiler.

Comment: Note that clang 10 *does* produce the [same error](https://godbolt.org/z/e4Ezr9).

Comment: `Derived` does inherit `Base::Nested` (an incomplete type), and can use it - e.g. you could write `class Derived : public Base { Nested* p; };` But that doesn't mean you can define `Nested` as if it were a member of `Derived`. E.g. this doesn't work either: `class Base { public: void f(); }; class Derived : public Base {}; void Derived::f() {}` - you can call `f()` from `Base` in `Derived`, but you can't define it as a member of `Derived`.

Comment: Now, what problem are you trying to solve, where you hope being able to do this would help? What is this legacy code, and what does "extract the Base class" mean? Show a realistic example. As written, this looks like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Suppose I have a class named MyClass, I'm going to mock that class.
There are two possible way:(1) let MockMyClass inherit MyClass, but that doesn;t work: the ctor of MyClass takes 15arguments, and initiate another service, which is resource-consuming.

Comment: Another way:(2) extract MyClass into BaseMyClass, then let both MyClass and MockMyClass inherit from it. But the problem is: methods in MyClass heavily rely on inner typedef(about 20) and nested class(about 10). I don't know how to extract them into the base class, without breaking the current code structure.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is this:

```
class Base
{
public:
    // Forward declaration
    class Nested;
};

class Derived : public Base
{

};

class Nested
{                                                                                                                                                                                                      

};

int main()
{
    Derived derived;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiles on g++, clang++